# Position image in center with minimum margin from left and right

Tags: html, css, image, center

I am inserting an image in my webpage. I want to position it in the center with minimum margin of 10px from left and right. Also, it should maintain its width according to media width. `margin: 0 auto` is positioning it in the center, but does not maintain a minimum margin of 20px from both the sides.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: Please add your codes.

Comment: you can use display: inline-block to place image in center and than margin: 0 10px

Comment: For all of that text, you could've made an example instead. Wrap your image in a div, give that div display:table and give the image display:table-cell. I hope this comment is as easy to read as your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png"/>
</div>
```